# How can Kneser-Ney Smoothing be integrated into a neural language model?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language-processing

I found a paper titled [Multimodal representation: Kneser-Ney Smoothing/Skip-Gram based neural language model](https://doi.org/10.1109/ICIP.2016.7532765). I am curious about how the Kneser-Ney Smoothing technique can be integrated into a feed-forward neural language model with one linear hidden layer and a softmax activation. What is the purpose of the Kneser-Ney in such a neural network, and how can it be used for learning the conditional probability for the next word?

**EDIT:**

Authors mention that we may obtain different mulitple labels from n-1 words integrating Kneser-Ney smoothing. It is not clear for me what these labels are. As I know, the output of a LM could be the next word. How is it possible to get more labels with the Kneser-Ney smoothing ?